# After autofilter make conditional statement to execute macro

Tags: vba

I have a list of macros created which all work on their own, and if run in sequence, also work.  To be preventative, I want to make my sequence into a separate macro which contains conditional statements, in case data doesn't exist.

Here is my attempt at a conditional macro, which doesn't appear to give me the desired result:

```
Sub KPIFull()

    Application.Run "RemoveFormatting"
    Application.Run "WorkBookSetUp"
    Application.Run "SeparateData"

If Sheets("RM Deliveries").Range("B2").Value = True Then
        Application.Run "RMDeliveriesOutput"
    Else: Next

If Sheets("RM TAT").Range("B2").Value = True Then
        Application.Run "RMTATOutput"
    Else: Next

If Sheets("FP Deliveries").Range("B2").Value = True Then
        Application.Run "FPDeliveriesOutput"
    Else: Next

If Sheets("FP TAT").Range("B2").Value = True Then
        Application.Run "FPTAToutput"
    Else: Next

End Sub
```

So, why doesn't this work for me... I use autofilter.  The intent of this entire macro is to take data from a database, put it into excel, and run this macro to get a full report.  How I did this was have the analyst place the database data into Sheet1, which is then copied to Sheets 2 & 3.  Sheets 2 and 3 autofilter with defined terms.

As I check if the value in cell B2 exists, and B2 may be filtered out, I still have the code run, which may cause an error if there are no rows left after autofilter.

What I would like is to take and modify this code to do something along these lines:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B").Contain="Term1, Term2, Term3"  Then
        Application.Run "RMDeliveriesOutput"
    Else: Next
```

My problem is I have no idea what to write in for the *contain="term1, term2, term3"* which might actually be correct VBA code.

Does anyone know of a way to do this type of searching as a condition?

---

Edit:

Tried the following, based on work with Xiaoy312:

```
Sub KPIFull()

    RemoveFormatting
    WorkBookSetUp
    SeparateData

    Dim abc As Integer
    Dim def As Integer

        Sheets("RM").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        abc = Selection.Rows.Count

            If abc > 2 Then
                RMDeliveriesOutput
                RMTATOutput
            End If

        Sheets("FP").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        def = Selection.Rows.Count

            If def > 2 Then
                FPDeliveriesOutput
                FPTATOutput
            End If

End Sub
```

Both FPDeliveriesOutput and FPTATOutput pull from FP! before doing their workflow.  If I can terminate the workflow at that stage, it may work, though the code still seems to be working, despite the "if" not being satisfied.  Any suggestions?

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Edit2:

This code seemed to work:

```
Sub KPIFull()

RemoveFormatting
WorkBookSetUp
SeparateData
RemoveHiddenRowsRM
RemoveHiddenRowsFP

Dim abc As Integer
Dim def As Integer

    Sheets("RM").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    abc = Selection.Rows.Count

    Sheets("FP").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    def = Selection.Rows.Count

        If abc > 2 Then

            RMDeliveriesOutput
            RMTATOutput

        End If

        If def > 2 Then

            FPDeliveriesOutput
            FPTATOutput

        End If

End Sub
```

It worked after I removed the hidden rows in my autofiltered sheets.

Comment: hm.. if you want to check if there is a value in a cell you go with `if IsEmpty(Sheets("RM Reliveries").Range("B2")) then` instead of `.Value = True`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, me how.  I missed it when I scrolled down to the first answer.  Thank you for the input and yes, that does work to correct "skipping" a macro in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no need to use `Application.Run` unless you want to do something dynamic.
  Simply call the subroutine without parentheses.
- It is unnecessary to test a variable against `True` in a condition. If it equals true, because it is true.
- The `Next` keyword is only used to mark the end of a `For` loop.

```
If (condition1) Then
    'do something if condition1
ElseIf (condition2) Then 'Keep in mind that this is optional
    'do something if condition2
'You can also add as many ElseIf below

Else 'This is also optional
    'do something if everything above fails
End If
```

Here is your code fixed

```
Sub KPIFull()
    RemoveFormatting
    WorkBookSetUp
    SeparateData

    'Unless you want to stop after 'RM Deliveries'!B2 contains something
    'Ill suggest you to replace the IF THEN....ELSEIF...THEN...END IF by
    'IF THEN ... END IF
    'IF THEN ... END IF
    'IF THEN ... END IF
    'IF THEN ... END IF
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("RM Deliveries").Range("B2")) Then
        RMDeliveriesOutput
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("RM TAT").Range("B2")) Then
        RMTATOutput
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("FP Deliveries").Range("B2")) Then
        FPDeliveriesOutput
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("FP TAT").Range("B2")) Then
        FPTAToutput
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to test a string is contained within another string use the `InStr` function and test if the result is not 0. `InStr` will return the position of what you are looking for.

```
instr(1, "QWEASDZXC", "ASD") <> 0
```

You can try this to test out if the sheet contains data other than just the header row

```
Sheets("FP TAT").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Rows.Count > 2
```

Comment: I managed to delete my first comment, not my second, which was incomplete... I have this tested out, and I don't appear to have this working for me.  Possibly I entered it wrong?  If Sheets("RM Deliveries").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Rows.Count > 2 Then
        RMDeliveriesOutput
    End If

Comment: I believe I found another way to do this, using something similar to what you've suggested.  Testing it now and will accept yours as answered and refer to my post with final outcome.  TBC... nvm, i was wrong.  I tried defining total columns used as a count and saying if that integer > 2 then to execute commands, but it doesn't appear to be working.          Sheets("FP").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        def = Selection.Columns.Count
               
       If def > 2 Then
            FPDeliveriesOutput
            FPTATOutput
         End If

Comment: Guess that didn't work... posted it after the "edit" note in my original post.

Comment: Took some work, but I used what you gave me and made it work; thanks a lot!  Accepted you as solved.